# Cargar bitmap con Glide

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide

Estoy intentando cargar un Bitmap con la librería Glide pero no existe ningún método para cargarlo y en la documentación tampoco lo encontré.

He estado buscando por mas sitios como EO inglés y encontré varios posts pero no llegue a entender bien que es lo que hacen. A ver si podéis ayudarme.

Os pongo en situación: 
necesito cargar un Bitmap porque las imágenes que quiero cargar en los ImageView las modifico para redondearlas y ponerlas como avatar y claro, al modificarlas se quedan como bitmap y no me interesa guardarlas modificadas en el dispositivo.

Todo esto es en un RecyclerView y había pensado hacerlo con Glide porque si lo hago de forma normal con : `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` se laguea un poco el RecyclerView.

Si alguien tiene otra solución que no sea hacerlo con Glide también es esuchada ^^

**EDITADO!!**

Esto es lo que hago para asignar el la imagen y lo que me gustaría cambiar y hacerlo con Glide

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ruta_imagen);
if (bmp != null) {
    viewHolder.imageAvatar.setImageBitmap(UtilidadesImagenes.getCircleBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Esto es el ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public ImageView imageAvatar;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
         super(v);
         imageAvatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivAvatar);
    }
}



public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap!=null){
        final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = Color.RED;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        bitmap.recycle();

        return output;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Las imágenes que se cargan a veces llegan a los 200KB que es cuando empieza a quedarse lagueado

Comment: Agrega tu código para que puedan revisar los desarrolladores amigo. Puede haber varias sugerencias o solución a esto.

Comment: Si usas ImageView.setImageBitmap() directamente en el ImageView sin usar un contenedor me parece ese debe ser el problema, creo que sería bueno agregaras tu código.

Comment: Ya añadí como lo hago, y no entendí bien lo de el contenedor =/

Comment: Creo que el problema son las imágenes, que tendría que al guardarlas de alguna manera para que pesaran menos.

Answer (score 1):

Para cargar una imagen usando glide:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load("ruta de la imagen o drawable")
    .centerCrop()
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Glide puede recibir una URI o una URL para la carga de imagenes en el control que le especifiques. En el siguiente ejemplo le paso la uri de un bitmap que genero al tomar una foto.

```
 Glide.with(this)
.load(fileUri.getPath())
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.centerCrop()
.crossFade()
.into(imgPhoto);
```

Si no tienes guardado tu bitmap, primero necesitas guardarlo y obtener la ruta donde lo guardaste

```
 public void saveBitmapToJPG(Bitmap bitmap, File photo) {
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(photo);
        newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.close();
    }
```

y ya que sabes que esta guarado y le pasaste la ruta, puedes obtener el URI y mandarlo a glide

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
        String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID },
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
                new String[] { filePath }, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            cursor.close();
            return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
        } else {
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El "problema" de eso es, que el bitmap que genero a partir de la imagen guardada en el dispositivo no me interesa guardarlo, de ahí que me interese cargar un bitmap directamente con el Glide =/

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente se te "lagee" por que la imagen es demasiado pesada. ¿Has probado a redimensionar la imagen antes de hacer el `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`?

```
int width = 120
int height = 120
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(miImagenBitmap, width , height , false));
```

Comment: Es por eso seguro, intente guardar las imágenes con menos resolución para ver si iba mejor y funcionó pero aun así sigue pillandose un poco, voy a probar eso que has dicho a ver que tal.